# SQL - Selecting a single row if duplicates are found

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table, I have a column named process_number and card_number. It is formatted like this:

---

```
process_number     card_number   name
1000               1             Joker
1000               2             Batman
1001               5             Bruce
1002               3             Alfred
1002               1             Oswald
1003               4             Lee
1004               6             Riddler
```

---

I need to create a view where card_number = 1 if is has a duplicate record in process_number. If it has a unique process_number I need to select it as is

Expected Output:

```
process_number     card_number   name
1000               1             Joker
1001               5             Bruce
1002               1             Oswald
1003               4             Lee
1004               6             Ridler
```

Comment: How about "GROUP BY card_number" statement?

Comment: @SergiuCostas That won't select the specific row that he wants.